# Hash specialization for table of function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, hash

Updates in **bold**

I am writing a hash function for a table of function pointers **with the limitation that the structure of the function pointers and function table cannot be modified** (i.e. they have been published to third-parties). Based on [Can std::hash be used to hash function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720064/can-stdhash-be-used-to-hash-function-pointers), std::hash can be used for function pointers. Adopting that, it yields the following solution.

The tedious part about this solution is that every time we add new APIs to FuncPointers struct, we'd have to modify the hash specialization to add the corresponding change (i.e. hashFunc(hashedValue, pFuncs->func3) ).

I am wondering if there's a better way to implement this hashing of function pointers so continuous modification to the hash specialization can be avoided?

```
typedef void (*func_type1) (int);
typedef void (*func_type2) (double);

typedef struct FuncPointers
{
    func_type1 func1;
    func_type2 func2;
    ...
} FuncPointers;

template <typename T> void hashFunc (size_t & HashedValue, T funcPointer)
{
    std::hash<T> hash;
    HashedValue ^= hash(funcPointer); // the XOR operator is randomly picked
}

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<FuncPointers>
    {
        size_t operator()(FuncPointers *pFuncs)
        {
            size_t hashedValue = 0;
            hashFunc(hashedValue, pFuncs->func1);
            hashFunc(hashedValue, pFuncs->func2);
            ...

            return hashedValue;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Here is a solution for `std::tuple` that is standard compliant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7115547/1774667 (the second part of the answer, the first part violates C++11 standard)

Answer (score 0):

Start with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7115547/1774667

It provides a `hash_tuple::hash<Tuple>` that is a valid decent quality hasher (with combining and recursion support!) for a `std::tuple`.

Next, change `FuncPointers` as follows:

```
struct FuncPointers:std::tuple<func_type1, func_type2 /*, ...*/> {

  // optional:
  func_type1 func1() const { return std::get<0>(*this); }
  func_type1& func1() { return std::get<0>(*this); }
  //...
};
namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<FuncPointers> {
    template<typename... Ts>
    std::size_t operator()( std::tuple<Ts...> const& funcs ) const {
      return hash_tuple::hash<std::tuple<Ts...>>{}(funcs);
    }
  };
}
```

which redirects your `std::hash<FuncPointers>` to invoke `hash_tuple::hash<std::tuple<...>>` on the parent of `FuncPointers`.  If you do not want to inherit from `std::tuple`, changing it to a has-a instead of an is-a relationship should be easy.

The optional `func()` accessors give you closer to the old interface (just requires a `()` added), but also adds boilerplate.

An alternative would be:

```
template<unsigned N>
auto func() const->decltype( std::get<N>(*this) ){ return std::get<N>(*this); }
template<unsigned N>
auto& func()->decltype( std::get<N>(*this) ){ return std::get<N>(*this); }
```

which changes `funcPointers.func1` to `funcPointers.func<1>()`, but gets rid of tonnes of boilerplate when you add a new `func`, and stays pretty similar to the old interface of `funcPointers`.

If there is not much code that is using the old interface, using `std::get<N>()` makes some sense.

If your names are more descriptive than `func1` and you only used that for the example, an enumeration of the function names can be used with `std::get` or `func<X>` above.  If you go with `func<X>` you can even make it typesafe (force the use of the named functions).

Comment: Thanks Yakk. One limitation I didn't mention (my bad) is that I cannot change the structure of the function pointers as well as the function table (i.e. these structures have been published to third-parties so we cannot modify them). I will take a closer look at your suggestion to see if I can rationalize it with that limitation.

Comment: @lancery you can write a `get_tie` method that wraps up each of the variables into a `std::tie` (which is about the same code as manually maintaining the `hash`), or you can wait for reflection to arrive, possibly before C++17.  A `static_assert` that (number of functions you handle) * `sizeof(` function pointer `)` `==` `sizeof(FuncPointers)` might be useful.

Comment: since this is a table of function pointers, can we make some simplifying assumption that they are all of the same size (i.e. via using size_t) and iterate through them somehow?

Comment: @lancery `auto begin = reinterpret_cast<void const*const*>(&fp); auto end = begin+sizeof(fp)/sizeof(void const*);` then do a cumulative hash on the range `begin` to `end`?  Dangers would include: padding between members, extra crap at front (go for POD), extra crap or padding at end.  We can make this a bit less quirky with some anonymous `struct` and `union` action -- willing to restrict which compiler you are using?

Comment: This is being compiled using VC++ Compiler. Do we have to worry about padding? My understanding is that given it's a direct struct definition (not member struct so don't have to worry about fat pointers) and that function pointers are either 4 bytes or 8 bytes so they are naturally aligned.

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better off making your `FuncPointers` a `std::tuple<func_type1, func_type2>`. Then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124153/15416) on hashing.

BTW, `typedef struct FuncPointers { } FuncPointers` is a C-ism which has never been necessary in C++.

Comment: Specializing `hash` for `std::tuple<Ts...>` is undefined behavior.  The linked answer uses a symmetric `^`, which is a bad idea when hashing.

Comment: @Yakk: I didn't state that you should specialize `std::hash`,  just provide your own hash as the second argument to `std::unordered_set`. You're right that plain `^` is a bad idea, but the relevant idea of the linked answer is to enumerate the tuple members.

Comment: The OP specializes `std::hash` -- replacing `FuncPointers` with `std::tuple` makes that not possible (well, possible, but no longer legal!).  The answer you linked to specializes `std::hash<std::tuple<Ts...>>`, which is undefined behavior (no diagnosic required), and what is worse usually works.  I'm just saying your answer will lead the OP (or someone else reading it) down the wrong path in 2-3 different ways at once.