# is it possible to convert a function pointer to an integer?

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to do something like this in a well-defined manner:

```
struct S
{
  static some_integral_type f() noexcept
  {
    return some_cast<...>(&f);
  }
};
```

The integer can be signed or unsigned. The result should be the same as the casts of object pointers to `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` produce. AFAIK casts to those are not guaranteed to be possible for function pointers. Even casts to `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t` might not work for all I know.

I need this so I can produce a unique "handle" from a function pointer, that I can then use in a `switch` statement.

Comment: What should the resulting integer be? The memory address?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. What do want to actually achieve?

Comment: If you _really_ have to do this, at least use [`(u)intptr_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/3425536) to avoid any data loss.

Comment: @zenith yes, but function and member function pointers are not object pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately, no this is not possible in the current C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29797882/278842

Comment: That answer is wrong and irrelevant.

Comment: @Puppy indeed, on both counts.

Comment: You can put a function or even a member function pointer into the signature of a function template, declare a static variable within that function template, and return the address of that variable (potentially casted to some `intptr_t`).

Comment: @dyp That's what I'm doing now yes, but I've still asked for another solution to avoid the wasted variable.

Comment: @dyp Please check my answer, if you like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no.

First, member-function-pointers (and member-pointers) are hairy beasts the standard says *very* little about.
So, let's ignore them for now.

Next, it might not even be possible to round-trip plain old function-pointers through `void*`, and the standard only defines a type for round-tripping data-pointers through integers, if the implementation supports such:
`(u)intptr_t`.

Naturally, if your implementation has a large enough integer-type, you can manually do it by reading the pointer as an `unsigned char[]` and combining it to a single numeric value, the operation then being reversible.

Be aware that equal function-pointers can result in different numbers if you go that route though, as the same pointer can have multiple possible representations (for example padding bytes, non-value-bits, segmentation)...

Comment: Be aware that equal function-pointers can result in different numbers if you go that route though... Why?

Comment: @user1095108: Well, let's go to x86, segmented memory as an example: There can be multiple ways to refer to the same function, with different segment-offset-pairs. Also, there might be padding in it (32bit-offset, 16bit-segment, 2 Byte padding).

Comment: On POSIX-compliant systems you're guaranteed to be able to convert a function pointer to a void pointer; and vice versa

Comment: @Deduplicator check my nonstandard solution please.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to select an integer of the same size as the function pointer with a metafunction- the required size being `sizeof(void(*)())`. However, there's no guarantee that any such integer type exists.

Realistically speaking, casting it to void* or intptr_t is gonna work on pretty much all the mainstream platforms.

Comment: I could just try with `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` then. If those don't work, nothing will.

Comment: @user1095108: Actually, some compilers support integers bigger than `intmax_t`, as they couldn't change the latter due to ABI-compatibility.

Comment: @Deduplicator How about `unsigned long long` and `long long` then?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Can std::hash be used to hash function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720064/can-stdhash-be-used-to-hash-function-pointers)

> In a previous attempt I attempted to cast the function pointer to
>   void*, which isn't allowed and doesn't compile (see:
>   https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr
>   for details). The reason is that a void* is a data pointer, while a
>   function pointer is a code pointer.

Comment: I'm not looking for a hash, as those can collide. That is, 2 different function pointers might produce the same hash.

Comment: Since you can do equality checks with member function pointers, that should not be the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328238/how-to-hash-and-compare-a-pointer-to-member-function for more info.